# How to get a single decimal value from Web Api and display it in Angular 10 using httpClient

Tags: angular, typescript, asp.net-web-api, angular-httpclient

Trying to get a single decimal value from Web Api to display it in Angular 10 using typescript. Cant display the value that i got from Web Api in Angular index.component.html, dont know where am getting it wrong.

Here is my code:

**Web Api method:**

```
     [ResponseType(typeof(InvoiceAddline))]
    [Route("api/InvoiceAddline/GetInvoiceSum")]
    public IHttpActionResult GetInvoiceSum()
    {
        decimal you = 0;
        var line = from e in db.InvoiceAddlines
                      
                   select e;

        var addlines = line.ToList();
        you = addlines.Sum(x => x.Total);

        return Ok(you);
    }
```

**Shared service:**

```
 import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class SharedService {
  readonly APIUrl="http://localhost:55482/api";
  readonly PhotoUrl ="http://localhost:55482/Photos/";
  constructor(private http:HttpClient) { }
 
  getInvSum(){
    return this.http.get(this.APIUrl+'/api/InvoiceAddline/GetInvoiceSum');
  }

}
```

**index.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {SharedService} from 'src/app/shared.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-index',
  templateUrl: './index.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./index.component.css']
})
export class IndexComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private service:SharedService) { }


  invsum:any=[];



  ngOnInit(): void {


   this.service.getInvSum().subscribe(data=>{
      this.invsum=data;

    });
  }

}
```

**index.component.html:**

```
<div class="row">
       
  <div class="col-12 ">  
  

Sub Total: {{invsum}}


    </div>

  </div>
```

I am able to get value from Web Api but struggling to display it in angular. Hope someone can assist.

Comment: What is the issue? Does it print in console.log in your component when you recieve the response?

Comment: It doesn't display anything, but Web Api is able to display the value when tested, in Angular nothing is displayed.

Comment: this.service.getInvSum().subscribe(data=>{
      this.invsum=data;
      console.log(data)
    });
Then check if it displays in console, this way we are sure Angular got it

Answer (score 1):

I realized that there was extra api on my method.

My APIUrl is like:

```
readonly APIUrl="http://localhost:55482/api";
```

My method was like:

```
getInvSum(){
    return this.http.get(this.APIUrl+'/api/InvoiceAddline/GetInvoiceSum');
  }
```

Instead of:

```
 getInvSum(){
    return this.http.get(this.APIUrl+'/InvoiceAddline/GetInvoiceSum');
  }
```

After removing api on my method it start to display.